# how to make a abc pyrmid

Tags: c, loops, output, alphabetical

i wrote a code and i dont know how to continue from here .. i want to build an abc pyramide from start to back (a ,aba,abcba..etc) for example

```
a
a b a
a b c b a
a b c d c b a
```

etc..

this is my code , thanks :)

```
void aba(int lines)
{
    //int i = 97;
    char a = 97;
    
    for (int i = 97;i <= lines + 97;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",i);
        for (int j = 97;j <= lines + 97;j++)
        {
            if (j == i)
                break;
            
            printf("%c%c", j,i);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

void main()
{
aba(3);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you ask a question, and you show your code, you should describe what in your code doesn't work or show the output it produce and tell what is not good in the output. It looks like an assignment you got, so I won't just write the answer, you should try by yourself and get help on specific issue. You can edit your question to add more info. Also remove either C or C# tag, and keep the correct one.

Comment: Are you looking for **c** or **c#** solution? These languages are different

Comment: a c solution , yes it is an assigment i got.. i've been working on this for 4 hours and i cant get through.. i tried my best, cant get any better than this.

Comment: any better than what? what happens when you run that code? why is that wrong or insufficient? anyway, how do you call it? you need to show a _complete_ example.

Comment: i just call it from void main() { aba(3);}
my output is a , bab , cabac , dadbdcd . 
instead of my example i wrote in the description.

Comment: When I add a main function, the function `aba` does not produce the expected output. Please [edit] your question to create a [mre] or to add requested information. Don't use comments for this purpose. Before writing the code you should think about the algorithm. What do you have to do for e.g. the fourth line of the output? How does it differ from the third line? BTW: Using `'a'` instead of `97` would make your code clearer.

Comment: bodo , hey , it may be clearer if i use 'a' but longer , i wanted to keep it simple with a for loop and stick to the assci table .. i will edit the code thank you.

Comment: `main()` must return `int`

Comment: isnt only int main must return an int?

Answer (score 3):

As it is homework, I give you a hint, not the solution:

You should observe the pattern: All lines start with `a`.

When you numerate the lines from top to bottom starting with `0`, the line `0` has an `a` and `0` additional characters.
line `1` starts with the `a` and has `1` more upcounting character (`b`) and then `1` downcounting character (`a`).
line `2` starts with the `a` and has `2` more upcounting character (`b c`) and then `2` downcounting character (`b a`).
...
So, line `i` starts with the `a` and has `i` more upcounting characters (`b c d ....`) and then `i` downcounting characters (`... c b a`).

Now you have to translate that into code.

```
void aba(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //print here what all lines have in common
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            //print the upcounting characters
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            //print the downcounting characters
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i still have no clue how to do it.. i tried to make a countdown on the second loop 
i mean that the 2nd loop will be j = i and than j>lines ; j--; but it will output 
a single char every line.. 

do i have to use another for loop?

Answer (score 3):

If you have problems solving a given task always try to split it into smaller jobs:

Start by printing an `a` for every line of your pyramid:

```
void aba(int lines) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", a);
    }
}
```

Now you want to have a pyramid with one character in the first line, 3 in the second, 5 in the third and so on. You can produce this sequence using `(i * 2) + 1`:

```
void aba(int lines) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (i * 2) + 1 ; j++) {
            printf("%c", a);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The last step would be to increase the character in the first half of the line and decrease it in the last half:

```
void aba(int lines) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        char a = 'a';
        for (int j = 0; j < (i * 2) + 1 ; j++) {
            printf("%c", a);
            if (j <= i - 1)
                a += 1;
            else
                a -= 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: amazing , i would have never thought about that. 
2 things i didnt catch , how did it work as an assci code if it represents as a char , and 2nd question : why in the if(j<-i -1) part why did you minus i .

Comment: Your `char a = 97` is the same as `char a = 'a'`. The char `a` is equal the integer 97.  without the minus the increase of the character would not stop before the middle but after it. The second line would be `abc` instead of `aba`

Comment: oh, so it's equivalent  to a++ instead of a+=1 ? 
btw that's only half of the ex.. that 2nd part is the line reaches i , the outputs changes to latin charcaters.. i dont even know what is their codes in assci

Comment: Yes, `a++` is equal to `a+=1` if your compiler allows it. What do you mean with latin characters? You can put all 128 ascii characters into a char.

Comment: that's what i dont understand. the question says to make this pyramid and when the line reaches number 'i' the outputs changes to latin characters. i dont know if he ment to assci code of 'i' ... anyways thanks alot ! appriciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

It is not necessary that lower case letters follow each other without gaps. For example this in not correct for the EBCDIC table.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the required output can be obtained.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const size_t N = sizeof( alphabet ) - 1;
    
    while ( 1 )
    {
        size_t n = 0;
        
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number not greater than %zu (0 - exit ): ", N );
        
        if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        n %= N + 1;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            const char *p = alphabet;
            
            do { printf( "%c ", *p++ ); } while ( p != alphabet + i + 1 );
            
            if ( --p != alphabet )
            {
                do  { printf( "%c ", *--p ); } while ( p != alphabet );
            }               
            
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number not greater than 26 (0 - exit ): 26

a 
a b a 
a b c b a 
a b c d c b a 
a b c d e d c b a 
a b c d e f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a 

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 26 (0 - exit ): 10

a 
a b a 
a b c b a 
a b c d c b a 
a b c d e d c b a 
a b c d e f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i h g f e d c b a 
a b c d e f g h i j i h g f e d c b a 

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 26 (0 - exit ): 4

a 
a b a 
a b c b a 
a b c d c b a 

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 26 (0 - exit ): 3

a 
a b a 
a b c b a 

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 26 (0 - exit ): 2

a 
a b a 

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 26 (0 - exit ): 1

a 

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 26 (0 - exit ): 0
```

The part of the program that outputs the pattern can be placed in a separate function such a way that the pattern can be outputted in any file.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * display_pattern( size_t n, FILE *fp )
{
    static const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static const size_t N = sizeof( alphabet ) - 1;
    
    n %= N + 1;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        const char *p = alphabet;
            
        do { fprintf( fp, "%c ", *p++ ); } while ( p != alphabet + i + 1 );
            
        if ( --p != alphabet )
        {
            do  { fprintf( fp, "%c ", *--p ); } while ( p != alphabet );
        }               
            
        fputc( '\n', fp );
    }
    
    return fp;
}


int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        size_t n = 0;
        
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): " );
        
        if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        display_pattern( n, stdout );
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 5

a 
a b a 
a b c b a 
a b c d c b a 
a b c d e d c b a 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 4

a 
a b a 
a b c b a 
a b c d c b a 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 3

a 
a b a 
a b c b a 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 2

a 
a b a 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 1

a 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 0
```

If actually you want to output indeed a pyramid then the function can look as it is shown in the next demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * display_pattern( size_t n, FILE *fp )
{
    static const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static const size_t N = sizeof( alphabet ) - 1;
    
    n %= N + 1;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        const char *p = alphabet;
            
        fprintf( fp, "%*c ", ( int )( 2 * ( n - i) - 1 ), *p++ );           
        while ( p != alphabet + i + 1 ) fprintf( fp, "%c ", *p++ );
            
        if ( --p != alphabet )
        {
            do  { fprintf( fp, "%c ", *--p ); } while ( p != alphabet );
        }               
            
        fputc( '\n', fp );
    }
    
    return fp;
}


int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        size_t n = 0;
        
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): " );
        
        if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        display_pattern( n, stdout );
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now the program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 5

        a 
      a b a 
    a b c b a 
  a b c d c b a 
a b c d e d c b a 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 4

      a 
    a b a 
  a b c b a 
a b c d c b a 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 3

    a 
  a b a 
a b c b a 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 2

  a 
a b a 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 1

a 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 0
```

Comment: thank you ! , thank you for the time to write all this.